# Web interface for torque

Tags: cluster, batch

Can someone recommend a good web interface for [Torque](http://www.clusterresources.com/products/torque-resource-manager.php)? I'm interested mostly in monitoring the status of the job queues.

Answer (score 2):

[Job Monarch](https://subtrac.sara.nl/oss/jobmonarch/) looks promising...

Answer (score 1):

Can [this post](http://www.clusterresources.com/pipermail/torqueusers/2004-March/000401.html) be an aid?

Answer (score 1):

We have had great success with a program called [ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net).

From their web page:
`Ganglia is a scalable distributed monitoring system for high-performance computing systems such as clusters and Grids.`

Answer (score 1):

We use [ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) for monitoring our 2200 CPU supercomputing cluster. It's great, shows everything we need to see easily including the job queue, CPU loads, user metrics. I'd recommend it.

Comment: I didn't think ganglia had support for torque out of the box. I have ganglia installed and it doesn't show job queue status by default. What did you have to do to get it to show job queue info?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a WebInterface for Torque. Actually is @alpha stage and should be tested, but it works:

https://github.com/MatteoRagni/Force

(If you intend to use it or you like it, please star the project, so I'll understand if it worth spend my time on it)